# how to display no structure jsonString to NSTextView with structure dispay

Tags: objective-c, json, macos, nstextview

if I have a json string like this:

> {"api":"com.taobao.mtop.deliver.getaddresslist","v":"2.0","ret":["SUCCESS::调用成功"]}

I want to display it in NSTextView like this:

```
{
    "api": "com.taobao.mtop.deliver.getaddresslist",
    "v": "2.0",
    "ret": [
        "SUCCESS::调用成功"
    ]
}
```

How can I do it with Objective-C in my mac app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were my app, I'd pass the JSON data into the [NSJSONSerialization class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html), specifically the [`JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:) method.

And with the NSDictionary that the method creates, you can get a string from that and then set the contents of the NSTextView to that string.

If you want it to be prettier, you might need to use [a third party library](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) or [formatter](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2013/11/10/pretty-printing-json-in-objective-c/).